# Using jQuery DateTimePicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, nuget, jquerydatetimepicker

I have been trying to use the XD Soft jQuery plugin found here :

[datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker)
I used NuGet to install it to my asp.net mvc project.
I want to use the inline date and time picker within my form
Here is the HTML

```
<head>
<title>Create</title>  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>

</head>

<h2>Create</h2>


@using(Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Event</h4>

<hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class =   "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { @id = "datetimepicker3", @style ="width:150px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes   = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new {     @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")   
</div>

@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
    inline: true,
    lang: 'ru'
});
</script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

 }
```

However at the moment only an ordinary calendar is displayed allowing the user to choose the date, month and year but not the time as well which is what I need. I have tried a few different plugins and tutorials but I've not been able to get one that works as expected. Any help would be great as I've been stuck on this for ages and haven't been getting anywhere thanks.

Comment: Try this plugin [DateTime Picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Comment: To help narrow down the problem, remove all page elements (the form) and simply use `<input id="datetimepicker3" type="text" />`. Get that to work to verify you have all the proper scripts and styles loaded properly. Then add helpers, forms, ... According to that plug-in's [github page](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker) the `lang` option is obsolete.

Comment: @Jasen I removed all the form elements and put in the line you suggested while keeping all my scripts and styles and the calendar displayed the way I wanted it to. Do you have any suggestions on what the problem with my form is? Thanks!

Comment: Reintroduce the parts you removed one-at-a-time. Start with the datepicker's `EditorFor()` See how the rendered html changes. Do that until it breaks or until you have recreated your desired page.

Comment: @Jasen thank you very much, I changed EditorFor to TextBoxFor and that seems to have works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what was wrong I needed to use TextBoxFor rather than EditorFor within the form. Here is the View with the change implemented.

```
<head>
<title>Create</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />

</head>

<h2>Create Event</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class  = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { id =   "datetimepicker3", @style = "width:150px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new {   @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes   = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new {   @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
        inline: true,
        lang: 'en'
    });
</script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

Comment: It would be useful to others if you could explain the markup differences.